# IntelliJ IDEA export Runnable program as Uber Jar

Tags: intellij-idea

In Intellij IDEA, If a Java or Groovy class has "main" method, Intellij provides an option to Run the program and it figures out the classpath based on the classpath of the module. `Run <className>.main()`  works fine. 
However I want to `export a Uber jar` for the corresponding  including all the required jars from the classpath so that I can run this program somewhere else. I did not see an option in Intellij to export the java/class as uber(fat) jar. I am not looking for a gradle/maven build script to create the jar. Checking if Intellij has an option to do this automatically.
Using Intellij Ultimate Edition 14.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this feature is what you are looking for:

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

The key step is to customize the artifact and select "select to target JAR".