# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after building jar file in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, noclassdeffounderror

The structure of my first app is simple:

```
libs
  opencsv-3.8.jar
  yamlbeans-1.0.jar
out
  artifacts
    ...
  production
    ...
src
  META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
  pl.krzysiu
    App.java
    CsvReplacer.java
```

Everything is fine during the compile and running the program. After building artifact jar file in the default out\artifacts directory, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/yamlbeans/YamlException
```

when I try to run it by java -jar CsvReplacer.jar command

The libraries are included inside the jar file (they are there after unpacking it) - they are added to *Libraries* section in *Project Structure* (separately - one file per one lib), the whole *libs* dir is included in the *Dependencies* tab of *Modules* section (with export checkbox checked) and the *libs* dir is added in *Output Layout* of *Artifacts* section similarily.

The manifest file contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: libs\yamlbeans-1.0.jar libs\opencsv-3.8.jar
Main-Class: pl.krzysiu.App
```

Why the libs aren't visible for the App? If I copy this dir manually to the CsvReplacer.jar file's location - everything works fine.

The structure inside CsvReplacer.jar file looks like:

```
libs
  opencsv-3.8.jar
  yamlbeans-1.0.jar
META-INF
  MANIFEST.MF
pl
  krzysiu
    App.java
    CsvReplacer.java
```

IDE: Intellij IDEA 2016.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Java classloaders cannot find a JAR file embedded inside another JAR file.

You have two choices when making an executable JAR with dependencies.

1. Create a so-called uberJAR file by merging the contents of the dependent JARs into your main JAR.

   References:

   - [IntelliJ IDEA export Runnable program as Uber Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31387087/139985)
   - https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/
2. Give your JAR a "Class-Path" manifest attribute to tell it where the (external!) dependent JARs are located.

You can't give a `-cp` and a `-jar` option together.  But another alternative would be to get rid of the `-jar` option and use a `-cp` argument to specify the classpath.

Alternatively, you could implement a custom classloader that can load from a jar inside a jar, or use something like [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot).