# Build Offline Jar file with maven dependencies intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

How can I build **Offline** Jar file with maven in intellij?
My system doesn't access internet connection.

Comment: Are you trying to build a jar and you don't have internet connection now, or are you trying to build a jar that contains all the dependencies you need so it can be used on another system without an internet connection?

Comment: Actually it can be used on another system without an internet connection

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387087/intellij-idea-export-runnable-program-as-uber-jar. A jar with all dependencies is referenced as a "uberjar". Also look the Maven shade plugin https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-shade-plugin-create-uberfat-jar-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building jar doesn't explicitly require internet connection. It will require only if the jars your application requires are **not present in** in ~/.m2 folder.

I just built a jar using `mvn clean install` without connecting to the internet. So make sure you have all the dependancy jars present in the ~/.m2 folder before you start building. Otherwise it will anyway give compilation errors.